# Why is it impossible to format Kendo UI datepicker outputs correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

```
<form class="SecForms" action="@Url.Content("~/Credit/GenerateStatement")" method="post" id="credit_form">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.PracticeId)
    <div class="setup-content" id="purchasing">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Start Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 input-group">
                        @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
                            .Format("dd-MM-yyyy").Culture("en-GB")
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">End Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 input-group">
                        @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.EndDate)
                            .Format("dd-MM-yyyy").Culture("en-GB")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="BDuttonBar">
            <div class="BButtRightOptom">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success lyprocess" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('spinny').style.display = 'block';">Generate</button>

                <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch" fa-spin loadingSpinner" id="spinny" style="font-size:24px;float:right;display:none;"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Despite having explicitly set the format on the DatePickers, it still tries to output with dates formatted as `2019-30-09` (for September 30th). With a date like this selected, and I suspect, any date with a day-of-month greater than 12, the form fails to submit.

I've tried setting `Culture = ...` at the top of the page per the [official Telerik DatePicker Globalization guide](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/globalization) but this hasn't made one iota of a difference.

As a workaround (see below), I've gone ahead and reformatted the dates to **ACTUAL** DateTime values, but as previously mentioned, the inability to submit the form on the selection of particular dates remains a problem.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateStatement(GenerateStatementViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Recreate the datetimes from the inputs because everything is stupid and nothing formats properly.
        var startDate = new DateTime(model.StartDate.Year, model.StartDate.Day, model.StartDate.Month);
        var endDate = new DateTime(model.EndDate.Year, model.EndDate.Day, model.EndDate.Month);

        // Continue work processing the form.
    }
}
```

I don't know what else to try. How do I get this ridiculous Telerik nonsense to actually work as specified?

When I check the information for `Kendo.Mvc.dll` it shows Version is 2019.1.115.440 (part of Kendo Web Extensions for ASP.NET MVC in Telerik's 2019 R1 suite)

Comment: Can you share your version of Kendo? Maybe that could influence.

Comment: Updated question. Here it is as well: *When I check the information for Kendo.Mvc.dll it shows Version is 2019.1.115.440 (part of Kendo Web Extensions for ASP.NET MVC in Telerik's 2019 R1 suite)*